# How to get the xUnit Fact Attribute 'DisplayName' argument inside the Fact test method

Tags: c#, selenium, automated-tests, xunit, xunit.net

```js
        [Fact(DisplayName = "Test Demo Display Name")]
        [Trait("Category", "Internal")]
        [Trait("Category", "All")]
        public void Demo()
        {

            // I like to get the DisplayName 'Test Demo Display Name' here(inside this function) for    furthur processing.


        }
```

I like to get the DisplayName 'Test Demo Display Name' here(inside function) for further processing. How to do that?
I know there are some option to get the Traits details using the TraitsHelper class. Is there any similar approach available for Facts attribute as well.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if xUnit has some specific mechanism to help you do this, but you can easily write your own helper to do this.

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
```

```
static class XUnitHelper
{
    internal static string FactDisplayName()
    {
        var frame = new StackFrame(1, true);
        var method = frame.GetMethod();
        var attribute = method.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(Xunit.FactAttribute), true).First() as Xunit.FactAttribute;

        return attribute.DisplayName;
    }
}
```

Inside your unit test method, call `XUnitHelper.FactDisplayName()`. Of course this won't work if there is any nesting - for example, if you call this helper in another method which is itself called from the unit test method decorated by `Fact`. To handle a case like that, you'd have to write more complicated code which traversed the stack (in fact, that's why the `1` is passed to the constructor of `StackFrame`; we want to skip past the stack information for the helper method itself).

Comment: Currently i am using below code for getting the 'DisplayName'. I am looking for any specific xUnit functions for doing this.                                                            MethodBase method = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod();
FactAttribute attr = (FactAttribute)method.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(FactAttribute), true)[0];
string nameForReport = attr.DisplayName;